# Google Sheets, how to send email with attachment to every customer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet, with some tabs, in one tab i make statement for my clients, there i select a customer in B2 and using a query formula i get the desired data, after that i have a script to first hide blank rows and then send that email with the pdf as attachment, and i do thins only when need send that email.

[image]

this is my script:

```
  function HideEdoCta() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Edo Cta');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow, 1);
  var data = range.getValues();

  //Rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == 1) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
    }
  }
  sheet.hideColumns(4, 1)

}

function UnHideEdoCta() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Edo Cta');
  sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getDataRange());
}


function MailEdoCta(email, subject, body, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Edo Cta');
  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();

  if (valueToCheck == true && casa != '') {

    HideEdoCta()

    SpreadsheetApp.flush()

    var email = sheet.getRange('D1').getValue();  // Enter the required email address here
    var casa = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
    var subject = 'Estado de Cuenta Sky';

    var body =
      "Hola, <strong>" + casa + "</strong><br><br>" +
      "xxx.<br>" +

      "-- <br>" +
      "<strong>xxx</strong><br>"
      ;

    // Base URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
      + '&size=letter'                          // paper size legal / letter / A4
      + '&portrait=true'                        // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&scale=1'                              // 1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'              // fit to page width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'    // hide optional headers and footers
      + '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false'     // hide page numbers and gridlines
      + '&fzr=false'                            // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      + '&gid=';                                // the sheet's Id

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

    // Uncomment the line below to save the PDF to the root of your drive. 
    //  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf")


    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "",
      { name: 'xxx', htmlBody: body, attachments: [response] }
    );

    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    UnHideEdoCta()

    sheet.getRange('C1').setValue(false)
    sheet.getRange('B2').clearContent()
  }
  else {
    sheet.getRange('C1').setValue(false)
  }

}
```

in this script i have a validation that if there is a customer selected in B2 and C1 is true, send the email, because the trigger is set to run every minute.

now what i need is send the same email, every 5th of the month to all my customers automatically (i only have 24 customers)

how can i make this possible without selecting one by one ?

any help please ?

[here is a sample sheet with sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hdKKPA2znSoWg8xafvT0Tlj-PBZbfoRehg4J45Dl0d8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: it seems that there is something missing in your script: how do you start the MailEdoCta function? and where is located the list of customers?

Comment: I start the MailEdoCta function with a trigger, and the list of customers is in the tab BD

Comment: I use an approach in which I can deploy a separate function and template for each customer thus making it  possible to utilize fairly simple scripts for each unique need and not having to pile a lot of functionality into one script.

Comment: @Cooper can you explain me and help a little more, with that idea please ?

Comment: What kind of trigger is the `MailEdoCta` function? @UnionMovil

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function mailing() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = doc.getRange('listOfCustomers').getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1]) {
      sh.getRange('B2').setValue(data[i][0]); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
};
```

a copy of your spreadsheet would have been appreciated for testing.

Comment: sorry, I have added now a sample sheet for testing purposes, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hdKKPA2znSoWg8xafvT0Tlj-PBZbfoRehg4J45Dl0d8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried like this, but got "error, maximum execution time" ..... function mailing() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = doc.getSheetByName('BD').getRange('A2:A25').getValues()

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sh.getRange('B2').setValue(data[i][0]);
    MailEdoCta()
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(i*1000)
  }
};

Comment: Thx for the sample sheets, but the scripts are far too complex for me. If you get "maximum execution time" error, it is because may be you have too many customers at once, so I suggest first to test with about 10 customers and check if the mailings are ok. Then proceed by batches.

Comment: Hi, I did with 10 and its ok ... so how can I make it by batches ?

Comment: I think the main problem is creating all the pdfs is where I get the problem .... Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: An idea to do it in batches: put checkboxes in the right part of customer emails, redefine listOfCustomers to cover both columns ... I updated the script according to this idea

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment from above:

This is the basic script that reads the information spreadsheet and calls the email function along with an object that identifies the template and other important information.

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Emails');
  const [hA, ...dt] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const vs = dt.filter(r => r[0] && r[1] && r[2] && r[3] && r[4] == 'Send' && r[5]);
  const idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  vs.forEach(function (r) {
    let obj = { index: idx, row: r }
    this[r[5]](obj);//This executes the function named in r[5] and passes it obj
  });
}
```

This is one of the functions that sends emails or creates a draft:

```
function sendEmails103(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('libImages');
  const [hA, ...dt] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  let imgObj = {};
  vs = dt.filter(r => r[idx['filename']] == obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']])
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let params = { muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    let aurl = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems/" + r[idx['mediaItemId']]
    let resp = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(aurl, params).getContentText());
    let burl = `${resp.baseUrl}=w${r[idx['maxwidth']]}-h${r[idx['maxheight']]}`
    imgObj[r[idx['Key']]] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(burl).getBlob();
  });
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']]);
  let html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  if (html) {
    if (obj.row[obj.index['operation']] == 'Create Draft') {
      GmailApp.createDraft(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    } else {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']],obj.row[obj.index['Subject']],'',{htmlBody:html,inlineImages:imgObj,replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']]});
    }
  }
}
```

This probably not for everyone, but I like having more room to customize my letters and having been a web developer for a long time I'm quite comfortable composing letters in html which is probably not true of everyone.